# use sparksql in Idea but not find table

Tags: apache-spark-sql

In spark-shell,I execute the sentence:"spark.table("show tables").show",It can show the list of table in my hive.But the same sentence in Idea not word.It can't find anyone.

I have set the $SPARK_HOME/conf in my Modules' dependencies with the runtime scope.The hive-site.xml is work.

help me please.

Comment: I run the sparksql by Scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer.It must use the enableHiveSupport().I am foolish